# How to write two methods in single apex wrapperclass for visual force page? I need to fetch field valuesfrom salarydetail__c monthly for currentyear

Tags: apex, visualforce

Apex:

```apex
public class SalaryRewards {
    public List <salaryInfo> lsalaryInfo{get;set;}
    public List <Salary_Detail__c> salarydetail{get;set;}
          
    public SalaryRewards(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        lsalaryInfo = new list <salaryInfo>();
        salarydetail = new list<Salary_Detail__c>();
        salarydetail =[SELECT Id, Professional_Tax__c, BasicAllowance__c, HouseRentAllowance__c, Skill_up_Allowance__c, PF__c, SpecialAllowance__c, TotalEarnings__c,TotalDeductions__c, NetPay__c, createdDate 
                       FROM Salary_Detail__c 
                       WHERE createdDate = THIS_YEAR ];
        for(integer i=0;i<System.now().month();i++) {
            salaryInfo  sinfo = new salaryInfo ();
            sinfo.month = datetime.newinstance(2013,1,1).addmonths(i).format('MMM');
            sinfo.count = 0;
            lsalaryInfo.add(sinfo);
            system.debug('salary-month===>'+lsalaryInfo);
        }
    }
      
    // lsalaryInfo = new List <salaryInfo>();
    public getsalary() {
        for( Salary_Detail__c sal :[SELECT Id,  Professional_Tax__c, BasicAllowance__c, HouseRentAllowance__c, Skill_up_Allowance__c, PF__c, SpecialAllowance__c, TotalEarnings__c, TotalDeductions__c,  NetPay__c, createdDate 
                                    FROM Salary_Detail__c 
                                    WHERE createdDate = THIS_YEAR ]) {                
            //Integer Basic_Allowance  = integer.valueof(sal.get(''));
            lsalaryInfo.add(new salaryInfo(Salary_Detail__c= salarydetail.BasicAllowance__c));
            system.debug('salary-month===>'+lsalaryInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Visualforce:

```html
<apex:page standardController="account" extensions="SalaryRewards" showheader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:pagemessages ></apex:pagemessages>  
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:pageBlocktable value="{!lsalaryInfo}" var="sinfo">
            <apex:column value="{!sinfo.month}" headervalue="Month"/>
            <apex:column value="{!sinfo.Basic_Allowance}" headervalue="BasicAllowance"/>
        </apex:pageBlocktable>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a wrapper here, you can just query that data directly:

```
public AggregateResult[] aggregateSalaryData { get; set; }
```

...

```
aggreateSalaryData = [SELECT 
  CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate) month, 
  SUM(BasicAllowance__c) BasicAllowance  
  FROM Salary_Detail__c WHERE createdDate = THIS_YEAR 
  GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate)];
```

You can show these values directly on the page:

```
    <apex:pageBlocktable value="{!AggregateSalaryData}" var="sinfo">
        <apex:column value="{!sinfo['month']}" headervalue="Month"/>
        <apex:column value="{!sinfo['BasicAllowance']}" headervalue="BasicAllowance"/>
    </apex:pageBlocktable>
```